# JQuery .on only firing once on dynamically generated elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have the following problem.  I am trying to add a two events to a table of checkboxes.

Here's an example of the html.

```
<body>
<div id='container'> //static element, everything beyond this element is dynamic
 <div id='pane_x'>
  <div id='bottom_x'>
   <div id='bottom_left_x'>
    <div id='results_x'>
     <div id='list_x'>
      <div id='table_1'>
       <table>
        <tbody>
         <tr>
          <td>
           <input type='checkbox' name='blah' id='blah_obj.id_x' class='blahblah'>
          </td>
         </tr>
        </tbody>
       </table>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to select the checkboxes only hopefully by using a prefix selector [id^='blah_'].  I am able to get the code working for the first pane ie: pane_0, but it doesn't fire on pane_1 or beyond.

```
jquery(document).on("change", "[id^='blah_" + obj.id + "']", function() {
//code here
});
```

There may be nesting errors as I just made an approximate estimate of the html.  The weird thing is I can see them by using a daisy chained .children() statement, but I can't select the input elements.

Since the comments don't support the same code blocks as this section I'll just add it here:

```
jquery(document).on("change", ".checked", function() {
 var ids = jquery(this).attr("id").split("_");
 if (ids[0] === "blah")
  //do code
 }
});
```

edited the id for clarity.  The id structure is "blah_" obj.id "_" individual iterator.  So 3 checkboxes on pane 0 would look like this:
blah_0_0
blah_0_1
blah_0_2

there are 2 other sets of checkbox lists on this page that I do not want to target with these functions, that is why i'm using the prefix selector.

Comment: are there many inputs with the same id? Like 2 inputs with the same id in 2 different panes?

Comment: I think you should use `.live()` with dinamically generated elements.

Comment: where is `obj.id` defined? Why not use the checkbox class as selector?

Comment: What does `obj.id` contain? WHy are you using `id^=` if you are matching the entire id? That would make the selector for `blah_1` also match `blah_10`, `blah_11`, et.c.

Comment: Ok, I just saw that `.live()` is deprecated, so it should be the right choice...

Comment: update I was able to get it working, though it's really ugly.  Since the checkboxes can have 1 of two classes checked or unchecked.  I wrote the same code targetting both classes as so.
    jquery(document).on("change", ".checked", function() {
     var ids = jquery(this).attr("id").split("_");
     if (ids[0] === "check") {
      //do code
     }
    });

though looking for a more elegant solution.

Comment: @HugoDozois kind of, everything after the _ is essentially the same, ie all of the elements contained in pane_0 have the _0 suffix.  but there aren't any ID's that are exactly the same.

Comment: @charlietfl obj.id is defined in the root of the file, it essentally just represents a number (which coresponds to the pane it's referencing)

Answer (score 1):

The point of using `startsWith` selector is not to try to complete the whole value as you are doing with `obj.id` if `obj.id` is even defined.

Following would find all `input` with ID's starting with `'blah_'` either existing or in the future.

```
jQuery(document).on("change", "input[id^='blah_']", function() {
//code here
});
```

Using the class as selector makes even more sense if they all share a common class

```
jQuery(document).on("change", "input.blahblah", function() {
//code here
});
```

Also note you have typo in `jquery` should be `jQuery` unless you have defined it otherwise in your own code

**Important note** ID's may not be repeated in a page, in case you have been repeating the same checkbox ID. They must be unique by definition

Comment: The reason why I want to use the startsWith selector is that there are multiple sets of checkboxes on the page.  I don't want to select all of them with these functions, just a subset of them.  ie those with the check_ prefix.  Also, the id is a bit longer than I put in my example.  it's actually blah_obj.id_x, if i had 3 checkboxes it would look like this
obj.id = 1;
blah_1_0
blah_1_1
blah_1_2

and so on.

Comment: OK.. so you aren't finding all of the collection, you need to provide more refined details on differences between ones you want filtered out. Can you modify classes? Or is there some ancestor you can use to help filter. Some live html would help... can easily grab sample from browser

Comment: I am finding blah_0_x, but not anything else blah_1_x blah_2_x and so on are not being affected.  Unfortunately I can't get live data since it contains a lot of confidential info.  I tried adding a specific class to the elements i wanted to grab, but for some reason it wasn't writing the classes correctly or another function is overwritting them.

Comment: what about tree hierrchy? Are they in different columns etc? Class sounds like simplest path if you can get server to manage the logic for adding class to ones you want. Can also use `data-` attributes other than ID to help in markup

Answer (score 0):

here another sample :

```
$("body").on({
    click:function(){
        // where $(this) is the current item changed
    }
}, "input.blahblah");
```

​